After salesforce agent accepts the call, conversation does not start
We are trying to build AWS Connect and Salesforce connection.
done:

enabled cloud voice
created a contact center and Amazon Connect instance
added agents to the contact center
on the AWS side built the IVR flow that calls SF Flow
not mapped amazon and salesforce queues

On the salesforce side, we created a flow where we defined Queue for the routing. So we expect that call will be transferred to the agent from the queue

The problem is that we want to use routing on the salesforce side.
For this we use routing configuration Routing Model   Most Available not external. I am not sure, if this is possible...
Now the agent can recieve call in salesforce, but the conversation does not start. The call we be opened is finished, and the contact on his phone is on hold.
we finish amazon ivr flow with the block transfer to queue. I am not sure - is it only one way to finish ivr flow and start call in salesforce? As I understand - without mapped queues we can't transfer call to the queue, if we use Routing Model as Most Available. The problem is that Amazon doesn't know about salesforce Id

